# My Laptop is slowed down to freezing and taskkiller.exe is doing it by eating up memory

Tags: performance, popups

I don't know how I may be got attacked with malware, but my laptop is slowed down to hell. I checked the Task Manager, there I found that a command line "C:/Windows/system32/taskkiller.exe" is taking up all my memory. It pops up one after another after another, my PC is so slow that I can't even take the offline version of Antivirus (Bitdefender, Avira) from my Android to PC.

I tried switching off Windows Defender for good, no results. I know, all I need is to get the Antivirus in my Laptop. I even tried to kill "taskkiller.exe" by deleting from Command Prompt (Admin) by trying "del taskkiller.exe". It said,"Access Denied".

I have Windows 10,

Comment: Please read the Help section. Please do NOT use gross and offensive terms, even in oblique references. Please limit your phrasing to the clear and professional. You have a virus, and you should follow the standard procedures for removing it. Disabling Windows Defender is not the correct or standard procedure for cleaing a virus.

Answer (score -2):

You will need to find a flash drive that is empty to temporarily speed up your PC.

**How to speed up Windows 10 using ReadyBoost?**

1. Connect the USB drive to your Windows 10 PC.
2. Go to My Computer or This PC.
3. Now, right-click your USB drive to open the context menu and select Properties.
4. Under the ReadyBoost tab, you can allocate space for the ReadyBoost feature or use the complete USB drive.

TaskKiller.exe is a command line task killer. (if its popping up, you have a problem)

> Processes can be ended by process ID or image name. taskkill replaces
>   the kill tool.

meaning somebody or some update program is running tasks in the background for you. I suggest you figure out how to go to safe mode and see if it still happens.

Comment: When one has a virus, using ReadyBoost to speed the system up is not considered the best course of action. The correct course of action is to diagnose and remove the viruses and malware, which will usually happily result in the speeding up of the system without requiring such bandaid solutions as ReadyBoost.

Comment: @music2myear this is the first time i ever heard of that. A computer that you cant even click on antivirus is still a slow computer. Meaning a upgraded ram set wont make things worse.

Comment: ReadyBoost is not RAM, and requires a particularly expensive and uncommon type of storage device to offer even moderate performance. His issue is that he has processes that are using all available resources. Throwing more resources at the problem will not resolve it. Attacking and removing those processes will.

Comment: @music2myear but how can you even logically argue a point where he cant even launch anything? How do you consider that a better alternative to a something that i suggest at least allows a level of troubleshooting. Your argument doesnt solve the problem.

Comment: There is an exhaustive and regularly updated list of methods for malware removal in the link I suggested as a duplicate of this above. OP should read that and follow it. When one cannot run any processes within the running OS, the best course of action is to find a way to deal with the problem from outside the OS. Methods for doing so are among the suggested solutions at the link.

Comment: It's not that I'm not giving a solution, or that I'm attacking the person offering a solution: it's that there is a very good solution already given on this site, improved over years of effort, and I have pointed OP to that solution.

Comment: @music2myear though as much as you think you are offering a solution you technically arent. Its like pointing out that society has solved the issue of weight gain, you are fat, and go online and see how to lose the weight. Thats not a argument that helps anyone.

Comment: I suggest that you read more about StackExchange and how it works. There are questions about virus cleanup posted daily here. Because the methods for virus cleanup are pretty consistent across all viruses, and because it makes sense that for such a frequently asked question that will have essentially the same answer we create one place where we refer all who ask, that is what we do. Further, as a long time tech pro I stand by my assessment of the efficacy of ReadyBoost and where the effort in this solution should be made.